# Regex replace total string

Tags: javascript, regex, xml

I have and XML file with items that contain this string:

`<field name="itemid">xx</field>`

Where `xx` = a number from 50 to 250.

I need to remove the entire string from the whole file.

How would I do this with a Regex `replace`?

Comment: are you trying to accomplish this using the command line? Can you be more specific? I see someone provided an answer using Javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```js
str = str.replace(/<.*>/g,'');
```

See an example for match [here](https://regex101.com/r/uR4eY7/4)

```js
var str = "<field name='itemid'>xx</field>";
str = str.replace(/<.*>/g, 'replaced');
console.log(str)
```

**Explanation:**

- `<` matches the character `<` literally
- `.*` matches any character (except newline)

  - Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed `[greedy]`
- `>` matches the character `>` literally
- `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

---

#### If you want to be more restrictive you can do this:

```js
str = str.replace(/<field name\=\"\w*\">\d*<\/field>/g, '');
```

See an example for match [here](https://regex101.com/r/uR4eY7/5)

```js
var str = '<field name="test">200</field>';
str = str.replace(/<field name\=\"\w*\">\d*<\/field>/g, 'replaced');
console.log(str)
```

**Explanation**:

- `<field` name matches the characters

  `\=` matches the character `=` literally

  `\"` matches the character `"` literally

  `\w*` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

  - Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed `[greedy]`

  `\"` matches the character " literally

  `>` matches the character `>` literally

  `\d*` match a digit `[0-9]`
        -  Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

  `<` matches the character `<` literally

  `\/` matches the character `/` literally

  `field>` matches the characters field> literally (case sensitive)

  `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

Comment: not sure you need to escape `<` and `>`. I know it will work with it escaped, but for readability-sake, the fewer escapes used, the better.

Comment: AFAIK (and TBH I am not regex expert) using like that it will literally match the character

Comment: It does match the literal character. See my comment: "I know it will work with it escaped...". The point that I'm making is that this is an unnecessary escaping. It makes the resulting regex more difficult to read. It's preferable to be more deliberate. I noticed you're using regex101.com, (you should cite this in your answer). I encourage you to reconstruct the regex on regex101.com without `\<` and `\>`. You will see that `<` and `>` match the characters literally as well.

Comment: The example is linking to regex101, no need to link more :) I notice that without the escaped, I already tried both ways, I guess I can improve the first example, the second one make sense since is to be restrictive :)

Comment: Not to belabor this point, but it shouldn't make a difference whether it's escaped in the first or in the second example. Whether `<` or `>` is escaped or not, they will match the literal characters. That's the whole point I'm making. Neither `<` nor `>` are regex special characters. They are not regex metacharacters. They do not and therefore should not be escaped. Restrictiveness doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace a tag especially XML tag you must be sure that you capture everything from *opening* to *closing* tag. In this case RegExp should *look back*.

```
var re = /<(\S+)[^>]*>.*<\/\1>/g;
var m ='some text <ab id="aa">aa <p>qq</p> aa</ab>test test <p>paragraph </p>'.replace(re,'');
console.log(m);//some text test test
```

`\1` matches `(\S+)`
`\S+` one or more non-white-space characters